# Nginx look in directory if not exists pass to upstream backend

Tags: nginx, proxy, load-balance

We are using nginx as load balancer between two webserver

Is it possible to have nginx look if a requested file exists in a specific local directory (some minified css/js files, some images) and if yes, serve the file directly, if no pass the request to the upstream backend?

Comment: Did you have setup caches in nginx configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what the try_files directive is for.

```
try_files /local/directory @backends
```